# format a created field in mysqlquery

Tags: php, mysql

My query looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tid5 AS SELECT start, slut, vstart, vslut,    arbtid, arbtim, arton, nitton, tjugotva,
(3600*HOUR(sl_tid)+60*MINUTE(sl_tid)+SECOND(sl_tid)
-3600*HOUR(t24)-60*MINUTE(t24)-SECOND(t24))/3600 AS e24 FROM tid4;");
```

Columns sl_tid and t24 are in time format. The created column e24 gets a "decimal(14,4)" format. i want it to be something like "10,20". Iaw 2 decimal.

Comment: And where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TRUNCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)

```
$result = mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tid5 AS SELECT start, slut, vstart,
vslut, arbtid, arbtim, arton, nitton, tjugotva, truncate((3600*HOUR(sl_tid)+
60*MINUTE(sl_tid)+SECOND(sl_tid)-3600*HOUR(t24)-60*MINUTE(t24)-SECOND(t24))/3600, 2)
AS e24 FROM tid4");
```